# Python Find Latest Epoch Time and Format As String

Tags: python, time

I am using Python to run a query in my database and I want to return the latest epoch time of a column

```
import time
recent_time = 0
for row in rows:
    time = row[0]
    if time > recent_time:
        recent_time = int(time)
print "Latest Time: %s" % time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(recent_time))
```

but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the variable referencing the module `time` with the contents of `row[0]` for each row in turn. Simply rename your variable to something else so you don't get the namespace clash:

```
import time
recent_time = 0
for row in rows:
    time_entry = row[0]
    if time_entry > recent_time:
        recent_time = int(time_entry)
print "Latest Time: %s" % time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(recent_time))
```

Comment: Doh! Not sure how I did not see that.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code:

```
import time

latest_time = max(int(row[0]) for row in rows) # find the latest epoch time
print(time.ctime(latest_time))                 # format as string (local time)
```

If it is relevant; add handling of empty results (your current code returns Epoch in this case).